# Can we... bring the forums back?

Tags: community

When I first joined the CiviVerse, there was one place to go to get questions answered, see previous discussions, and meet fellow community people.

Now there are several places. But the Stack Exchange doesn't facilitate discussion, or trading of ideas to produce a single unified solution: people offer either a right answer or a wrong answer, and the asker either accepts it or rejects it. But only a single answer wins.

Additionally, I can't easily find a list of recent discussions in a different area. Someone may have an idea on how to improve things in a rarely used area - but where can they take these ideas where they will be easily seen by anyone interested in that area? GitLab? But then that's segmented from the Stack and Chat communities. In the forums I could go to a section and see it, and tagging doesn't work nearly so well.

Some conversations take place in chat. But if I encounter a problem, and ask it, there's no easy way for another person to google and come across the same problem. It's nearly impossible to get anything from chat hiatory, which is where the experts typically hang out. So their knowledge isn't as widely visible.

I feel that the forums offered a great bridge between all these options, and I only needed to keep track or be involved in one community. Now there are several.

Comment: This question maybe belongs in civicrm meta, but I partly agree. However I think it was a little bit about outsourcing/sharing infrastructure and also people resources with the existing CMS and other communities here, since there is some crossover and they're already here.

Comment: This is a meta issue - but it belongs on GitLab and it's something I've been asking about - I'll get a Lab post up in the Community section.